# MVC3 Site scripts and CSS not loading

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

Deployed MVC3 site to 2008 R2 Server, with IIS 7.5..

Basically CSS and Javascript libraries are not being loaded (e.g. In Firebug the CSS tab states that "There are no rules").

I've read elsewhere that the IIS_USR account needs to have permissions to see those files, so I've :

- right clicked on the site
- select edit permissions
- select Security tab
- added the "IUSR_[machinename]" users where [machiname] is the server
  name
- granted read and execute privs

Also as answered  in ([Do MembershipProviders in ASP.net MVC affect stylesheet links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167074/do-membershipproviders-in-asp-net-mvc-affect-stylesheet-links?rq=1)) I've added an autorization section for the content directory thus:

```
<location path="Content">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Also.. As a matter of last resort I've amended the asp.net v4.0 app pool to use the LocalSystem identity rather than ApplicationPoolIdentity in case this was the issue, but alas not.

What have I missed?

Comment: How you are referring the css/js files?

Comment: use the firebug NET tab to see what all files are loading from which path and which are failing

Comment: Examples are 
    <link href="@Url.Content("../Content/roleindex.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
and 

    <link href="@Url.Content("../Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

The NET tab doesn't seem to show anything...

Comment: @Shyju tell a lie, net tab lists the files but they all get 500 errors - Internal Server error. Paths look ok though..

Comment: I am having the same problem with windows server 2012 and IIS 8

Answer (score 1):

I bet you've hardcoded the urls to those resources in your views, ilke this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/foo.js"></script>
```

instead of using url helpers which is the correct way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/foo.js")"></script>
```

Also get rid of the `<location>` tag from your web.config.

Remark: did you meant IIS 7.5?

Comment: Hi Darin.
I'm using url helpers...
<link href="@Url.Content("../Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
And also tried without the razor syntax to no avail
...<link href="../../Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

I might as well get rid of the <location> tag as id did nothing...

Comment: You have to use the ~ with the Url.Content() helper.

Comment: Cheers @ZippyV, amended accordingly but still no luck. e.g.
`<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/roleindex.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: In the `Net` tab of FireBug are those scripts served correctly? What status code does the server return when they are requested by the browser?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov All are getting 500 - Internal Server error. Paths look ok.. eg 
http://myservername/mySiteName/Content/Site.css

Comment: And is there some exception stacktrace that is being shown? Also can you see the error in the server's EventLog?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov In the eventlog there's an error to do with sharepoint when serving the css file... (!)
`Exception information: 
  Exception type: HttpException 
  Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
 
Request information: 
  Request URL: http://[servername]/Content/style.css 
  Request path: /Content/style.css`

There are 2 issues - #1 the path should be http://[servername]/NewBO/Content/style.css not http://[servername]/Content/style.css , #2 - sharepoint!

Comment: Are you referencing other css files within roleindex.css or Site.css?

Comment: OK, I've just got the site working via a workaround.
The css and js files were throwing up Sharepoint errors as listed above, which is obviously rather odd. 
Uninstalling Sharepoint (I'm lucky to be able to do that on the server I'm on) didn't solve it, and I'm still getting the same error. The server install can therefore be assumed to be "in a right old state"...

Comment: ...However, after creating a new site on a new port number, rather than in an app in the default web site has allowed me to get round the problem for now. I'm assuming I'll need to re-install IIS at some point to get rid of whatever is left of sharepoint, but this Q is best left alone.

Comment: @Fetchezlavache - I am having the same issue and creating a new site did not fix the problem.  Please post if you come across any more information.

Comment: Wish I could help @DanKaufman, unfortunately this was the only time I've come across this issue and that work around solved it for me. Obviously if you have the option to add to another server altogether I'd try that - I'd wager my issue was due to past remnants of a sharepoint installation (that was no longer used and wasn't functioning on that server), or maybe a failed sharepoint uninstall.

Comment: @Fetchezlavache - thank you for the response. I figured it out and answered it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642225/500-internal-server-error-requesting-any-resource-files-css-js-images-in-an/18706638#18706638

Basically, the msi install was creating the wildcard mappings automatically, but that IIS metabase entry didn't play well with IIS8.  I don't know if it works with IIS7.