# 500 Internal Server Error requesting any resource files (css, js, images) in an .Net MVC 3 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, windows-server-2012

UPDATE: Things I tried - see answer below for solution

1. I installed a fresh MVC3 site and it served up the resources properly.  That eliminated the machine.config settings as a problem.
2. I then when section by section in the web.config to see if any particular changes in web.config caused the problem.  When the configs were identical, the fresh site still worked and the old site was still broken.
3. I uninstalled IIS, reinstalled IIS, and then installed apps again in an attempt to clear any settings that were lingering around.  Still borked.
4. I then used publish (instead of msi deploy) to new directory.  I used the iis option to "Create Application" on new directory of exact same code that is broken.  Things worked perfectly.
5. I assumed file permissions, so I deleted offending directory and renamed new working version to old directory name. Site was still borked.  This made me assume that some iis setting that is not in the machine.config or web.config is to blame.
6. I used IIS 6 Metabase explorer (yes I used it on IIS 8 site) and saw quite a few entries that were not in the working site.  After deleting one by one, I found it was the "scriptMaps" entry that was being added during our MSI install causing a problem.  This was added to automatically add wildcard mappings during install.  It works on IIS6, but apparently not on IIS8.

We have an webforms and MVC3 application that look like one application. This is deployed in many environments (2003, 2008, Win 7) and works properly.  I have just set these applications up on a new Windows Server 2012 machine and everything works except getting resource files for the MVC site.  The browser gets a

```
500 Internal Server Error
Server Application Unavailable

The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.

Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
```

The resources are referenced in the _layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=EmulateIE8' />
    <title>@this.Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2012.2.607/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Sentri7/scripts/jquery-p1s.banner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Sentri7/scripts/jquery-p1s.patientsearch.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sentri7/content/jquery-p1s.patientsearch.css"></link>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sentri7/content/jquery-p1s.banner.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/quantifi/resources/application/css/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/quantifi/resources/application/css/styles.css" />
    @(RenderSection("PageHead", required: false))
</head>
```

as well as using the telerik scriptmanager:

```
@{
    Title = "Reportable Conditions";
    SelectedSubTab = SubTabIndex.Reportables;
    Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(dg => dg
        .Add("~/Scripts/ReportableConditions/List.js")
        .Add("~/Scripts/ClientObjects/GridSettings.js"))
        .OnDocumentReady("bootStrapUI()");
}
```

If I try to navigate directly to the javascript file, I get the same error:

```
http://[server]/S7D/Scripts/2012.2.607/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
```

Some weird stuff:

1. If I IISReset and hit the js file, it will work the first request only.
2. Any js, css, or image requested from another (webforms) site (same app pool) on the server works fine.
3. There is nothing in the event log related to this 500 error.

I have tried adding permissions full permissions to the user that the app pool is running.  I have also added file permissions to the [Machine]\IUSR.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="telerik">
      <section name="webAssets" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebAssetConfigurationSection, Telerik.Web.Mvc" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="typeAliases" type="Spring.Context.Support.TypeAliasesSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web" />
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <spring>
    <context>
      <!-- Load web.config definition ** This resource reference is essential to define objects in the web.configs -->
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects" />
      <resource uri="assembly://CAS2/CAS2.CASLibDAO/_SpringObjects.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/App_Data/MvcApplicationContext.xml" />
      <resource uri="assembly://P1S.S7D.Core/P1S.S7D.Core.ApplicationContext/ApplicationContext-Common.xml" />
      <resource uri="assembly://P1S.S7D.Core/P1S.S7D.Core.ApplicationContext/ApplicationContext-DAO.xml" />
      <resource uri="assembly://P1S.S7D.Core/P1S.S7D.Core.ApplicationContext/ApplicationContext.xml" />
      <resource uri="assembly://P1S.S7D.Core/P1S.S7D.Core.ApplicationContext/Services.xml" />
      <resource uri="assembly://P1S.S7D.Common/P1S.S7D.Common.ApplicationContext/ApplicationContext-AuthModule.xml" />
      <resource uri="assembly://P1S.S7D.Common/P1S.S7D.Common.ApplicationContext/ApplicationContext-Web-Common.xml" />
      <resource uri="assembly://P1S.S7D.Core/P1S.S7D.Core.ApplicationContext.WCF/ApplicationContext.xml" />
      <resource uri="assembly://P1S.S7D.Core/P1S.S7D.Core.ApplicationContext/ApplicationContext-Circular-Reference-IPReporting.xml" />
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
      <!--cached objects-->
    </objects>
  </spring>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="P1S.S7D.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="P1S.S7D.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>



  <appSettings>
    <add key="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule.SessionFactoryObjectName" value="NHibernateSessionFactory" />
    <add key="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule.EntityInterceptorObjectName" value="MultiTenantInterceptor" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Server=dev-ct-nhsn.dev.rph.int;Database=aspstate;User ID=UID;Password=*****; Application Name=S7DSharedSession" />
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />

        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages pageBaseType="P1S.S7D.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="P1S.S7D.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="AuthenticationModule" type="Web.Handlers.AuthenticationModule,P1S.S7D.Web.Mvc" />
      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web" />
      <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate31" />

    </httpModules>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web" />
      <add name="AuthenticationModule" type="Web.Handlers.AuthenticationModule,P1S.S7D.Web.Mvc" />
      <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate31" />

    </modules>
    <!--    -->
    <handlers>
      <remove name="asset" />
      <add name="asset" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.0.4000" newVersion="3.3.1.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>    
  </runtime>
  <telerik>
    <webAssets useTelerikContentDeliveryNetwork="false" />
  </telerik>
</configuration>
```

All the resources, whether using Telerik or adding them with the script tag give the 500 error.  The controller and view show up correctly (without styles or javascript)

EDIT:

Register Routes:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
        routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );
    }
```

Comment: Have you set custom routing rules?

Comment: Are you actually deploying the assets to the server?

Comment: @Brett - Yes the assets are on the server.  In fact, after an IIS Reset, I can access the files once directly navigating to them.

Comment: @Andre Calil - I have added the routes we register to the question.  I think it is just the default standard routing.  This exact installation works on Windows 2003 server in QA and Production.

Comment: @DanKaufman Be sure to add static content on IIS setup: http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/05/23/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation.aspx

Comment: @AndreCalil - Static content is installed.

Comment: You can usually find the answer using [Failed Request Tracing](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis). It's a little bit tricky to use, but it will contain a very granular view of the failed request, and the reason for the failure.

Comment: @pattermeister - I enabled tracing, but I am not sure what it is telling me.  Anything in particular I am looking for.  I see where it sends the error I see on the client, but I don't see any type of exception or helpful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my edits.  The problem was an incorrect IIS setting that I found with the IIS 6 Metabase Explorer.

I used IIS 6 Metabase explorer (yes I used it on IIS 8 site) and saw quite a few entries that were not in the working site. After deleting one by one, I found it was the "scriptMaps" entry that was being added during our MSI install causing a problem. This was added to automatically add wildcard mappings during install. It works on IIS6, but apparently not on IIS8.

I am not sure why the files would get served up properly on the first request, but not subsequent requests, but removing the entry worked.  I could not find the "ScriptMaps" setting anywhere in the IIS GUI, but it is probably there somewhere.

Comment: For us, the error was a staticcontent mimemap being added in the web.config (woff) that must also have been installed at the machine level on our Azure web service. Once we added a remove element first then this fixed the problem and therefore the 500 errors.

Comment: Steve - I am glad you found the error.  I know I was banging my head against the wall for the longest time.  Nothing in the event logs.  Hope this helps people avoid all the frustrations I had.

Answer (score 25):

I was getting the same error when I published my site from local (Windows 7) to the server (Windows 2012).

My Local IIS had added this code:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Where as I needed this on Win 2012

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

It seems the newer version of IIS on Win2012 already has .woff added and instead of giving me any kind of details, it just went 500!

Comment: in my case, I had to remove woff2 as well.

Comment: for me it was something different. Maybe ms added appx or msix by default and after certain update it suddenly turned into plain text website. I was shocked since I tested it after deploying it two month ago. After removing these mime maps it started working properly.

Answer (score 1):

To my situation, I met this error when running my application on Window 8.0.

After I changed the mini type of .woff from 'font/x-woff' to 'application/x-font-woff' in IIS, it works well.(after I changed the mini type, my web config  added '' into staticContent automatically)