# page doesn't load css and js files after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amazon-web-services

I have the problem that my site does not load some css and js files when refreshing the site. When I first call the site everything is fine, its just after refreshing.

http://www.benty-fields.com/

Its a bit hard to debug, since on my local host everything works fine, its just a problem on the server. I am using the free tier on AWS, but I can't find any discussion about such a problem in connection with AWS, so I guess its my site. Has anybody have seen such a problem before and can give me some tips how to resolve it?
carl

EDIT:
I use chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) when I get the error, but I seem to get similar errors on firefox. 
The error will modify the website, since the css files are not loaded, but you can also seem them if you go to 
View > Developer > Javascript console... you should see something like that

```
GET http://www.benty-fields.com/static/css/popbox.css 500 (Internal Server Error)
(index):192 GET http://www.benty-fields.com/static/js/spin.min.js 
(index):185 GET http://www.benty-fields.com/static/js/moments.min.js 500 (Internal Server Error)
(index):191 GET http://www.benty-fields.com/static/js/bootstrap-select.min.js
```

[image]

Comment: looks good to me... can you tell us a specific scenario?

Comment: see my edits above... sometimes you have to hit refresh a couple of times... there seems to be a random element to it

Comment: [500-internal-server-error-requesting-any-resource-files-css-js-images-in-an](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642225/500-internal-server-error-requesting-any-resource-files-css-js-images-in-an)  might help you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that website is working fine for me, please have a look into attached image and let us know your thoughts,

[image: seems working fine for me]

Comment: did you press the refresh button? I uploaded a picture above showing the error messages I get....

Comment: i've pressed f5 and bg.jpg named file is showing in developer tool.

Comment: can you give me username/password?

Comment: oh I am so sorry you are right... this only happens when I am logged in... sorry I did not notice

Comment: your issue is now replicating. i'm looking into this and if i find anything then i will revert back to you.

Comment: in IE, i have found lot of warnings. can you please resolve those?

Comment: It seems, due to the slow response from the server(AWS), some css, js files are not able to download. you can use CDN for public css,js files. I have also open directly your given css and js files in separate browser tab and individually they are opening fine.

Comment: thanks sanjay... I was considering moving to digital ocean... maybe I should just do that

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution to the problem, since I guess there is a solution on AWS itself, but for me the problem was solved by moving to digital ocean...
cheers
carl

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Cloudflare, remember to clear its cache and enable development mode. This is something that used to nail me and waste hours of time when I first started running my sites through Cloudflare. Hope this helps someone.